# Exec in a new window

Tags: php, exec

I have a php bot script that loads forever till it dies. So i want to start other peoples bots with exec() but their bot works but mines stops responding. How can i start the bot in a new php window so my bot wont freeze?

My Code:

```
exec("php ".$input.".php");
```

Comment: What's a "PHP window"?  Do you just need to fork a new process?  If so, this might be a good place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: Yes, a new process. What is the code to do that, i couldn't find it in the page you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible solution, but if you're running your scripts locally on a windows machine you could use something like:

`exec('start "Window Title" "php" "script_name.php"');`

From there, each of the other scripts will be running in their own detached processes.  The downside is that your parent script won't be able to "kill" them.  They'll have to terminate on their own or you'll have to terminate them manually.

Comment: on linux that would be `exec("php ".$input.".php &");`

Comment: Can you put the code in a example lets say to start test.php

Comment: I tried exec('start "Window Title" "php" "new.php"'); but my main bot froze

Comment: The "start" command returns immediately unless you specifically add the `/WAIT` flag.  Add a few debug `echo` statements after the `exec` commands to see if it gets past them.

Comment: it doesn't work unless the bot that was started was killed

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have "new windows" per say, this would be an issue for Javascript.  You can open a new window in Javascript using the following syntax:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

I recommend opening a php file in a new window and having that file contain your `exec()` command be inside there.  [Check out more information on the specifics of this Javascript method here.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html)

Comment: I had thought of that, it didnt work

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do then?  Perhaps you should delay the execution of your `exec()` method.

Comment: i want to start it in a new pid/ new window.

Comment: Right, if I'm not too confused with what you're looking for, I believe you should launch a new Javascript window which opens a PHP file with your code inside.  Are you sure it didn't work?  I find that a bit surprising.  Will it work without being in a new window at all?